# CodeBlocks + OpenCV Compiles fine But gives a console window each time

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, mingw, codeblocks

I configured opencv with codeblocks 10.05 .I'm using mingw that comes with codeblocks.Each time The programs builds fine but while running it gives a console window instead of the way it should work [I was having same problem with sfml]
I tried some of the solutions from internet but didn't work.I've also configured wxwidgets with this mingw -- so I didn't want to use another mingw because earlier i figured out that I can't work with two mingw in my Pc.It gives me unknown bugs.
I can't understand if it builds fine then why it can't run [I mean why this console window comes each time]
One thing that I've not tried is getting another mingw because for that I've to build everything again from source.
Can it be a reason /Is something wrong with codeblocks MinGW?
Or,there may be other problems ?AS,it builds fine I think something is happening at the runtime [and as it builds that means no problem with opencv]
//I'm using windows 7 32 bit
Thanks.
I followed every step of this tutorial http://myncbi.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-configure-codeblocks-for-opencv.html
and built the library myself.But same problem.

```
#include "math.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// declare a new IplImage pointer ghfh
IplImage* myimage;

// load an image
myimage = cvLoadImage("Paris.jpg",1); //change the file name with your own image
//
//create a new window & display the image
cvNamedWindow("Smile", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//cvMoveWindow("Smile", 100, 100);
cvShowImage("Smile", myimage);

//wait for key to close the window
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow( "Smile" );
cvReleaseImage( &myimage );
return 0;
}
```

So,it should not show a console window [It shows only a console window even in release target]

Comment: You need to change the subsystem from console to Windows. It's in the project options somewhere, as well as available as a linker switch.

Comment: What is the problem with showing you a console window when running it?

Comment: I actually chose empty project [I have done SDL and openGL with empty project They worked fine] and then set everything up.It compiles fine but when I press run button[even in releaese target] I get a console window[nothing written and doesnot take any input character].
 "

Comment: And if I close the console window in the build log I get this "Checking for existence: E:\Robot\OpennCv_My_Built\bin\Release\OpennCv_My_Built.exe
Executing: "E:\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "E:\Robot\OpennCv_My_Built\bin\Release\OpennCv_My_Built.exe"  (in E:\Robot\OpennCv_My_Built\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 3 seconds)

Comment: And,Yeah I again built the whole library according to this tutorial..I follwed every step http://myncbi.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-configure-codeblocks-for-opencv.html But still same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,at last :-) After so many days,Thanks chris You actually gave a nice hint .I went to Properties - > Build targets -> Type : gUI application  ..And,I also put all the files from opencv bin directory to the project folder[where the exe is]although I'm not sure which one did the magic ,I'll try to figure it out soon :-D Now everything just works fine